# How do I make a separate mirror copy of an object (and do I need to?)

Tags: modifiers, rigging, objects

I am making my first character model and want him to have a left arm to go with his right one. As of right now, he has one object for his right shoulder, one for his right arm, one for his right leg, one for his left hip bag, etc. And these objects all just have unapplied mirror modifiers on, to give his right limbs some left counterparts. If I apply the mirror modifiers then the right and left arms will both be part of the same object. Do I want this when rigging? I am concerned because later, in the rig and for importing to Unity, I want to allow the bags around his waist to hang and bounce independent of one another. If the left hip bag is a mirror of the right object hip bag, will I be able to move it independently? What Imagine I want to do instead is to mirror the objects, then separate the mirrored components into separate objects, but I haven't managed to figure out how.

[image: One man army, Crunch Taylor!]

Comment: Rigging allows you to have all your objects merged in the one mesh and control movements around the bones with vertex groups. You should look more into that topic. Unity won't make sense of blender mirror modifiers so you will have to apply it at one point

Answer (score 1):

Use aplied mirror modifier, after! go to edit mode, in edit mode, go to mesh -> Separate Loose Partes! after! Go to object mode, and press in "new" object! and object -> set origin -> origin to geometry [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was perfect.